# Testing Views that use Devise with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am trying to get a previously passing rspec "view spec" to pass after adding Devise's `user_signed_in?` method to the view template in question. The template looks something like this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Welcome back.
<% else %>
  Please sign in.
<% endif %>
```

The view spec that *was* passing looks something like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "home/index.html.erb" do

  it "asks you to sign in if you are not signed in" do
    render
    rendered.should have_content('Please sign in.')
  end

end
```

The error it produces after adding the call to `user_signed_in?` is:

```
  1) home/index.html.erb asks you to sign in if you are not signed in
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/home/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__1932916999377371771_70268384974540'
     # ./spec/views/home/index.html.erb_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

There are plenty of references to this error around the web, but I have yet to find an answer descriptive enough that I can get my test passing again. I believe the problem has something to do with the view (which is being testing in isolation from any models/controllers) not having some key Devise infrastructure available. Your suggestions are appreciated.

Also, once the test passes, how would I test the other path (user already signed in)? I presume it will be very similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because you need to include the devise test helpers

Generally you'll add this (and you might already have) to spec/support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

But since you're creating a view spec, you'll want something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
end
```

Comment: Wow. I swear I tried that... However, trying it "again" my test passes. Thanks!

Comment: Docs: [RSpec::Core::Configuration#include](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration#include-instance_method)

Comment: It looks like the [RSpec::Core::FilterManager](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/FilterManager) looks at "metadata" like the `type` to determine which [Example](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example)s to run.

Comment: This worked for me. Since I was following this guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29 I also added a line to access a module containing login methods, so I also added:  "config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :view" and similar for controllers.

Comment: Awesome! Worked

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Rails [Composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/), this will guide you through a new rails project creation with options like testing, UI etc..

Create a sample project, cool thing is it will create all the test for you including view testing with devise. Then you can get an idea from those testing specs.

worked for me :D

HTH

Comment: That's a cool tool! However... it does not generate view specs. Just controller/model specs. Thanks.

Comment: ah, yes, but it gives cucumber for view testing, In my personal opinion, cucumber is the ideal tool for view testing

Comment: I am still learning how to BDD/TDD rails apps and the book I am using ([The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)) recommends Cucumber for high level testing, but also diving down into RSpec for detailed controller, model, and view testing. I might have to back off of the view spec since I can find no examples of anyone using RSpec for view specs using Devise.

Comment: I've yet to read a good reason for using Cucumber rather than RSpec for integration tests ("it's in English, sort of" counts heavily as an anti-reason). Not to mention that you're going to have to write code interspersed in your Cucumber junque to handle authentication and other Good Stuff™, right?