# Mock variables in view specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's the view I'm trying to spec:

```
%h2 Sign up

= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!
    %br= f.label :email 
    %br= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true
    %br= f.label :password
    %br= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off'
    %br= f.label :password_confirmation
    %br= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'off'
    = f.submit 'Sign up'

= render 'devise/shared/links'
```

And here's my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'devise/registrations/new', js: true, type: :view do
    it 'has a name field' do 
      render
      rendered.should contain('Email')
    end
end
```

That returns the error, `undefined local variable or method 'resource'`.

I was expecting that. I need to stub the variable.

Putting this before the render function:

```
expect(view).to receive(:resource).and_return(stub_model(User))
```

Results in:

```
  An error occurred in an `around(:example)` hook
    NoMethodError: undefined method `method_removed' for #<User not initialized>
    occurred at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
```

and

```
does not implement: resource
```

I assume it means the view doesn't implement resource...

Comment: I've never tested view before so I thought I'd try. And now I want to die!

Comment: Have you tried including the Devise test helpers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005444/testing-views-that-use-devise-with-rspec