# Devise and RSpec: Accessing current_user in specs

Tags: rspec, devise, helper

I am trying to access the devise helper methods in my view specs without success. I have seen a lot of similar questions on this before but none seem to answer my question specifically and the one that did, had a solution that did not work for me.

[Testing Views that use Devise with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005444/testing-views-that-use-devise-with-rspec)

Here is my rails_helper.rb file

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
  config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!
end
```

Here is the simple show.html.erb_spec.rb

```
describe "users/show.html.erb" do
   it "displays the users own profile" do
   member = create(:member)
   login_as(member, :scope => :member)
   user = member.user
   assign(:user, user)
   render(:template => 'users/show.html.erb')
 end
end
```

Now please keep in mind that I have a "Member model" for devise and a "User model" to hold profile information. They have a has one/belongs to one relationship.

I use the current_member helper (given by devise) and in my application controller I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   include UsersHelper
   helper_method :current_user
   before_action :authenticate_member!
   before_action :current_user
   before_filter :instantiate_search

  def current_user
      if member_signed_in?
       @current_user = User.find_by_member_id(current_member.id)
      end
  end
```

So basically I am also defining a current_user which is the current_member's user.

My issue is that in my show.html.erb file I use current_user

and my error is

```
   undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#   <Class:0x007fb6139e7f48>:0x007fb6139d6fe0>
```

I need to be able to access the devise current_member in my tests but I can't.

Any help would be gratefully received.

edit: This works but is hideous code.

Is there a better way?

```
 require 'rails_helper'

   describe "users/show.html.erb" do


       it "displays the users own profile" do
          @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:member]
          @member = create (:member)
          sign_in @member
          @user = @member.user
          def view.current_user
           @user
          end
           assign(:user, @user)
           render(:template => 'users/show.html.erb')
         end
       end
```

Comment: Hi, @GhostRider, I'm having the same problem. Have you found a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like

```
current_user = stub_model(:User)    
allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(current_user)
```

In the before block

Answer (score 0):

This may be an around about answer but I did the following and it worked.

In the controller for the view you are trying to test:
(I always build my own controller for Devise users, so that I can easily add pages but you could do that in `controllers/users/sessions`.)

```
def show
  @name = current_user.name
end
```

Then, in the `before(:each)` block you can do:

```
assign(:name, @user.name)
```

One of the corollaries I brought over from Django is that you can't call methods on objects in Views, which forces all of your logic into the controllers. This may be semantics but I have found my code to be a lot easier to read when I remove the logic from the views.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

To access current_user in helper specs.

```
let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }

it 'works with CSV template in physical bulk send' do
      allow(helper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
      expect(helper.say_hello_world).to eq('Hello World')
end
```